# Laravel mix dependency was not found error

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix, css-loader, jquery-filer

I'm using clean and latest Laravel 5.4. 
I have an error on `npm run dev`

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 4 errors                                                                                                  
This dependency was not found:

    * -!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{"url":true,"sourceMap":false}!../assets/fonts/jquery.filer-icons/jquery-filer.css in ./~/css-loader?{"url":true,"sourceMap":false}!./~/postcss-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"precision":8,"outputStyle":"expanded","sourceMap":true}!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

    To install it, you can run: npm install --save -!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{"url":true,"sourceMap":false}!../assets/fonts/jquery.filer-icons/jquery-filer.css
```

app.scss:

```
@import "node_modules/jquery.filer/css/jquery.filer";
```

jquery.filer.css:

```
@import url('../assets/fonts/jquery.filer-icons/jquery-filer.css');
```

I tried to change this path but it doesn't works anyway

Comment: You need to run `npm install` to install your dependencies

Comment: Nope, there is some problem with @import path